# Corda: Github path for corda-zulu-5.0-snapshot

Tags: corda

Can anyone point me at the github repo of this image?

corda/corda-zulu-5.0-snapshot

I'd like to check the dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker folder for the OS version is included in the main Corda repo: 
https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/docker/src/docker

To your specific question: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/docker/src/docker/Dockerfile is the file for zulu images